# How to concatenate a string from ordinary element values and from the option values of a multi selectable element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, multi-select, htmlcollection

I have the following js function. This is supposed to concat some of my form user inputs into a single "description" text area.

This works great for the strings, except for 'circuits' - which is an array. It will print out the first piece of the array - but not all pieces of the array. I am needing the array to seperate by comma.

```
function generateDescription() {
  document.getElementById('description').value =

    document.getElementById('description1').value + ' // Account Name: ' + 
    document.getElementById('company').value + ' // Issue Start Time/Date: ' + 
    document.getElementById('issue_start_time').value + 
    document.getElementById('am_pm').value + ' ' +
    document.getElementById('timezone').value + ' on ' +
    document.getElementById('issue_start_date').value + ' // Affected Circuits: ' +
    document.getElementById('circuits').value.join(',');
}
```

I am getting: create-new-trouble-ticket:509 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).value.join is not a function

Comment: Change last line to `document.getElementById('circuits').value.join(',')`

Comment: use array.join(',');

Comment: @user2680315 ... what is the value of the `circuits`-**id**entified element?.. maybe you debug `document.getElementById('circuits').value` yourself?

Comment: What's document.getElementById('circuits').value? Is it a string? Can you console.log it and tell us what the result is?

Answer (score 1):

To merge an array into a string use the `join` method:

```js
const array = ["0", "1", "2"];

console.log(array.join());

//the default seperator is a comma but you can change it
console.log(array.join(" : "));
```

Comment: Thanks - I just don't know how to concat my strings with the array.

Comment: @user2680315 What is the value of `document.getElementById('circuits').value`?

Answer (score 0):

The next provided snippet isolates the OP's problem for debug reasons ...

@OP ... how does the value assigned to the `circuits` element look like?..

***EDIT***

OP's answer

> *circuits is a multi-select dropdown*

The value of a (multi) [select element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Properties) is always the one of the first selected option element (or an empty string in case of no selected option at all).

Thus in order to concatenate all the values of any selected [option element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement#Properties) one needs to access the [HTML collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of all selected option elements via [`myMultiSelectElement.selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions).

This collection then needs to be transformed into an array (either by [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Syntax) or by [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)) in order to be processed more comfortably by e.g. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which, in the below example in cooperation with [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), covers the concatenation task ...

```js
function generateDescription() {
  const byId = document.getElementById.bind(document);

  byId('description').value = [[

      byId('description1').value,

      '// Account Name:',
      byId('company').value,

      '// Issue Start Time/Date:',
      `${ byId('issue_start_time').value }${ byId('am_pm').value }`,
      byId('timezone').value,
      'on',
      byId('issue_start_date').value,

    ].join(' '),

    '// Affected Circuits:',
    Array
      .from(byId('circuits').selectedOptions)
      .map(optionElm => optionElm.value)
      .join(', '),

  ].join(' ');
}

generateDescription();
```

```html
<textarea id="description" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea>

<input type="hidden" id="description1" value="dolor sit" />
<input type="hidden" id="company" value="amet" />
<input type="hidden" id="issue_start_time" value="04:30" />
<input type="hidden" id="am_pm" value="am" />
<input type="hidden" id="timezone" value="Amsterdam" />
<input type="hidden" id="issue_start_date" value="2020-11-04" />

<select multiple name="circuits" id="circuits" size="6">
  <option value="AA">AA</option>
  <option value="BB">BB</option>
  <option value="CC">CC</option>
  <option value="DD">DD</option>
  <option value="XX">XX</option>
  <option value="YY">YY</option>
</select>

<button onclick="generateDescription()">create description</button>
```

Comment: circuits is a multi-select dropdown

Comment: @user2680315 ... I updated my answer and also did provide some more context/information to this final solution/approach of mine.

Comment: @user2680315 ... are there still any open questions?